# How reliable is sewer re-lining?

Tags: plumbing

A couple of rough estimates from 2 plumbers for replacement of the sewer line from the back of the house to the street is around $20K. Sewer relining is advertised on the internet at around $6-8K.

So, is re-lining a proven and reliable process in 2015 (something I can have done and forget about for, say, 15 years)?

Thanks for advice/comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is reliable and very common with municipalities to extend the life of their sewers and water mains.

The only downside is that the inner diameter is reduced.  Also they do still need to dig at least two holes to install the liners.

When I had this quoted, the opposite was true - digging up the sewer was cheaper than a liner, so make sure to get a few quotes from reputable contractors.

Answer (score 1):

My son does the relining for a living. It's less invasive and is better and harder than what is already in the ground. I would say go with the relining.